# if else statement based on a binary array in numpy with vectorize function

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy array: one has binary variables `T = [0,1,1,0,0,...]`
The other has some random values: `X = [0.1, 0.2, 0.333...]`. I want to write a function that when `T[i]` equals to `0` `X[i] = 1 - X[i]`. I am wondering if there any vectorization function I can rely on instead of just `for` loop two array

Comment: [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) seems to be a good candidate.

Comment: I applied np.where but I can only get index of T. I am not sure how to apply the func with those index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) :

```
np.where(T == 0, 1 - X, X)
```

Full example:

```
# import module
import numpy as np

# Create T vector (random)
T = np.random.randint(0, 2, 20)
print(T)
# [0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]

# Create X vector (random)
X = np.random.random(20)
print(X)
# [0.60692623 0.4590666  0.25077907 0.39528167 0.31926095 0.97515345
#  0.00333958 0.24427309 0.4564238  0.22598126 0.52635721 0.04825686
#  0.88188174 0.11187227 0.93212834 0.63503694 0.52799418 0.07250929
#  0.45056039 0.22862652]

# Apply condition
X = np.where(T == 0, 1 - X, X)
print(X)
# [0.39307377 0.5409334  0.25077907 0.60471833 0.31926095 0.97515345
#  0.99666042 0.75572691 0.4564238  0.77401874 0.52635721 0.04825686
#  0.88188174 0.88812773 0.93212834 0.36496306 0.47200582 0.92749071
#  0.54943961 0.77137348]
```

Note: this solution assumes `T` and `X` have the same dimensions